# Absolute positioning ignoring padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a div with buttons at the bottom of a parent div that has a padding.

[image: current result]

The expected result is having the button resting on top of the padding (green area).

```css
.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritence from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url("../img/blank.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
#mcontainer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}
#header {
  height: auto;
}
#footer .link-item a {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0%;
  height: auto;
}
#footer .link-item:first-child {
  border-spacing: 0px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
#footer .link-item {
  border-spacing: 0px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div id="mcontainer">

    <div id="header">
      <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <span class="link-item"><a href="www.google.com" target="new">Button</a> </span>
      <span class="link-item"><a href="www.google.com" target="new">Button</a> </span>
      <span class="link-item"><a href="www.google.com" target="new">Button</a> </span>
      <span class="link-item"><a href="www.google.com" target="new">Button</a> </span>
      <span class="link-item"><a href="www.google.com" target="new">Button</a> </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"The expected result is having the button resting on top of the padding (green area)."_ - your expectations are wrong. Absolute positioning doesn't take padding in to consideration. If you know the amount of padding that your element has, use that value for your `bottom` position

Comment: Ok cool. That confirms my suspicions then. Is there a best practice to achieving what I want, without having to se the bottom for the "footer"?

My goal is to have a container in the middle of the page, with text at the top, and the buttons at the bottom, and I was under the impression that padding was the way to go.

Comment: Completely dissatisfied with @Turnip suggestion. Kindly take a look at inbox.google.com and its side navigation. There is padding added for absoultue positioned DIV, but it doesn't works in Firefox

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Absolute positioning does not take padding into account. A possible solution would be to add another container inside `.mcontainer`, that also has `position: relative`. That way, the inner container would respect the padding, and the absolute positioned element would be at the bottom of the inner container.

Comment: Elegant and simple. Thanks

Comment: This also works when you want the inner (absolute) div to take up the full width of the parent minus padding. In that case the inner div would need to have width set to 100%.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues here:

**First Issue**

Your buttons are absolute but the first parent element that has a relative positioning is the `mcontainer` element. Thus, the buttons will only be absolute to this element.

Remove `position:relative` from the mcontainer element, and set the `body` element to have relative positioning.

**Second Issue**

As Turnip had pointed out, padding doesn't get taken into account for absolute positioning. Thus, offset this by setting a negative `bottom` and `left` styling to the button container.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6smpvqq8/1/