# full div width bigger then parents width, box size doesn't work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Why is my cover wider than my element and my content? If I understand correctly, it covers the gunter, but neither `background-clip: content-box;` nor `box-sizing: border-box;` don't work. I also don't want to lose the rounded corners.

How to fix it?

```css
.myElem {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: max-content;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.cover:hover {
  height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row myDiv">
  <div class="myElem">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myElem">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Absolute positioning ignoring padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461611/absolute-positioning-ignoring-padding)

Answer (score 0):

Because of using row in your class .myElem have some padding added. you are already using bootstrap row then why don't you use col also you are giving .myElem width I removed width from it and wrap it in col-3 which is bootstrap class. Now both your content and cover have same width.

```
  <div class="myElem">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

change into this

```
  <div class="col-3">
  <div class="myElem">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
```

```css
.myElem {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: max-content;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.cover:hover {
  height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row myDiv">

  <div class="col-3">
  <div class="myElem">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-3">
  <div class="myElem">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't use columns because I will have more `myElem` elements, and I want the bootstrap to figure out how many elements should be in a row depending on the screen size. Adding col-3 does not allow that - always placing 3 elements in the row or 1 below the breakpoint.

Comment: No, but adding `col` does.

Comment: @Malvinka other way is using d-flex instead of row or removing padding from .myElem by using padding 0 !important

Comment: @MrUpsidown You are very right! I don't know why I haven't thought about it! Thank you! If you will turn your comment into an answer I will be very happy to accept it.